# Dropdown on div hover - dropdown alignment issue

Tags: html, css

I am making div with image and text. User can hover on this div to get dropdown.
I have issue on alignment of dropdown. I need it to be aligned with the right border of hovered div:
[image]
This is the code:

```
<div id="hoverDiv">
                <img alt="" width="32px" height="32px" src="http://www.fordesigner.com/imguploads/Image/cjbc/zcool/png20080526/1211776868.png" />
                <a href="#">Hover Me!</a>
                <div class="showme">
                    <p>
                        Hidden Stuff!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And CSS

```
#hoverDiv
        {
            width: 100px;
            height: 40px;
            float: right;
            margin-right: 5%;
        }
        #hoverDiv:hover
        {
            background: #ff0000;
        }
        #hoverDiv:hover .showme
        {
            display: inline;
            float: left;
            position: relative;
            margin-left: 5px;
            margin-right: 5px;
        }
        .showme
        {
            display: none;
            width: 100px;
            height: 200px;
            background: #0000ff;
            margin: 0px auto;
            float: left;
            left: -999em;
            padding: 10px 5px 0px 5px;
            border: 1px solid #777777;
            border-top: none;
            z-index: 10;
            position: absolute;
            left: auto;
            top: auto;

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **#hoverDiv**, add `position:relative`

In **#hoverDiv:hover div.showme**:
Remove `float:left` (redundant)
Remove `position:relative` (redundant)
Remove `margin-left:5px` && `margin-right:5px` unless you prefer them

In **div.showme**:
Remove `float:left` (redundant)
Remove `left:-999em` (redundant)
Replace `left:auto` with `right:0`

This [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DYxUJ/) has all the work done for you.

Comment: If I do that then I don't get dropdown.

Comment: @1110 Updated answer. Works 100% as intended from what I gathered.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean something like this?
http://jsfiddle.net/nbZmG/9/​​​

Here's another one -
http://jsfiddle.net/nbZmG/10/

Notice that in both cases, the width of the blue box is `120px`, and they are aligned according to the left and right side of the red box using `margin`.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding `margin-left:5px` on hover on your `.showme` div, remove that and it should align:

```
#hoverDiv:hover .showme {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0; /* here */
    margin-right: 5px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `#hoverDiv:hover .showme` remove `margin-left` and `margin-right`.

In `.showme` remove `margin` and modify `padding` to `10px 0px 0px 0px`, and `border: 1px` to `0px`.